# How to repeat it at every X intervals?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

on Get Property i am checking for DNS LookUp
But it is only executed at startup only..How to execute it at every X intervals

```
 System.Net.IPHostEntry ipHe = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName("www.google.com");
 return (@"Images/online.png");
```

Comment: I did a google search on the text "How to execute it at every X intervals" and got a bunch of good results. I'd suggest that you try that and then come back here if you get stuck implementing the code.

Comment: But this one is in Get set property How to do it there ??

Answer (score 1):

I'm making a lot of assumptions here, but I assume you are talking about keeping a WPF form updated with an "online" status that has an auto-refresh feature?  And doing so in the MVVM model.

If those assumptions are right, in your view model you can use a `System.Timers.Timer` that will fire at any `Interval` you specify, and it can execute any method you specify by hooking into its `Elapsed` event.

```
public class ViewModel{

    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        aTimer = new Timer();
        aTimer.Interval = 2000; // every two seconds

        // Hookup to the elapsed event
        aTimer.Elapsed += DoWork;

        // Have the timer fire repeated events (true is the default)
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;

        // Start the timer
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void DoWork(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) { 
        //do work here
    }
}
```